# Change/Remove a div id and refresh page async

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I would like to know how I can remove a div id on button click and add it on another button click so that the associated `CSS` loads. The page should then refresh asynchronously to display the changes.
So far I have been able to remove the id with button click.

```js
$("#Remove").on('click', function() {
  $("#slides").removeAttr("id");
});
$('#Add').on('click', function() {
  $("#main-wrapper > div").attr("id", "slides");
});

var pathname = window.location.host;

$("#Remove").click(function() {
  $("#main-wrapper").load(pathname);
});
//add code to refresh main-wrapper on any button click
```

```css
#slides h1 {
  color: black;
  background: grey;
  float: none;
}
h1 {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  width: 20vw;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Remove">Remove id</button>
<button id="Add">Add id</button>
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="slides">
    <div class="slides-container">
      <h1>This is a sample text</h1>
      <h1>You are awesome</h1>
      <h1>This is another line</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried with

Comment: http://codepen.io/shaneapen/pen/CdDku

Comment: To be honest buddy this seems like a bit of an odd way of going around it.  Normally `classes` are used for this kind of thing rather than ID's so I would suggest looking into `addClass` and `removeClass` but here's one of adding and removing the ID which however then relies on a class too! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ekJmD

Comment: Please attach your code from code-pen in your question.

Comment: That worked fine! Thanks! How to refresh the _main-wrapper_ with ajax for the changes to be seen?

Comment: Page refresh is needed in this case since most of the CSS is provided from the external js of the slider. Take a look here[Site](http://thetop5ofall.blogspot.in/2014/08/motivational-quotes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Remove").on('click', function(){
    $("#slides").removeAttr("id"); 
  });
  $('#Add').on('click', function(){
    $("#main-wrapper > div").attr("id", "slides");
  });
});
```

Comment: Cool! That worked fine! But how to call ajax for a page refresh? Isn't that necessary for the changes to be displayed while on my site?

Comment: No, CSS changes are instant. Aslong as you're not loading in another complete stylesheet, as far as I'm aware. Though even then it may well be. But you pretty much should always have all your styles in one stylesheet, unless your website/app is massive. And Rob was right, you should be using classes for this really. Tip: never ever use ID's in CSS, just classes :)

Comment: And to add a bit more, you don't use ajax to refresh the page, you use ajax to load external content.

Comment: Page refresh is needed in this case since most of the CSS is provided from the external js of the slider. Take a look [here](http://thetop5ofall.blogspot.in/2014/08/motivational-quotes.html)

Comment: I have added the div refresh to the code. However they seem to duplicate the buttons or some elements. Could you take a look at it and tell me why?

Comment: Seems fine to me, though I don't see why you're trying to refresh a div, it doesn't work like that. From that code it looks like you're trying to load the page into that div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60690/discussion-between-shan-eapen-and-evu).